# Tap Gesture on top of Drag Gesture Not Working with SwiftUI on Apple Watch

Tags: swiftui, apple-watch, gesture, watchos

I am running the view shown below on my physical Apple Watch Series 7 that has watchOS 10.0.1 installed. I am building the app with Xcode 15.

When the image is dragged below the `Text` with the blue background, the `TapGesture` does not work anymore. When the image is dragged so that it does not overlap with the `Text` anymore, the gesture seems to work fine.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ImageDetailView: View {
    @State private var offset: CGSize = .zero
    @State private var tapCount = 0

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
            VStack {
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    let dragGesture = DragGesture()
                        .onChanged { gesture in
                            self.offset = CGSize(width: gesture.translation.width, height: gesture.translation.height)
                        }
                    
                    Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "myImage")!)
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFill()
                        .position(x: geometry.size.width / 2, y: geometry.size.height / 2)
                        .offset(offset)
                        .gesture(dragGesture)
                }
            }
            
            Text("\(tapCount)")
                .frame(width: 45, height: 45)
                .background(Color.blue)
                .contentShape(Rectangle())
                .onTapGesture {
                    tapCount += 1
                }
        }
    }
}
```

I can not reproduce the problem on the simulator, only on the physical Apple Watch.

I've played around with [`highPriorityGesture(_:including:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/highprioritygesture(_:including:)) and [`simultaneousGesture(_:including:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/simultaneousgesture(_:including:)), but no combination so far has worked for me.

The `TapGesture` should work, even if the image has been dragged underneath it. Somehow it seems, if you tap accurately enough, that the gesture actually still works on the `Text`, but it ignores the blue background.